# Binding a dynamic fragment to a view

Tags: sapui5

I want to load in XML fragment dynamically via the view. I have some issues with loading the model binding in the view for the Fragment.

Why does this work?

```
<Input value="{mobile}" />
```

But this doesn't?

```
<core:Fragment fragmentName="{mobile}" type="XML" />
```

**Controller**

```
setFragmentNameToView: function(){          
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
            mobile: "com.xxxxxxx.fragment.fieldsFragment"
        });

        var bindingContext = new sap.ui.model.Context();
        bindingContext.oModel = oModel;
        bindingContext.sPath = "/";

        this.getView().setBindingContext(bindingContext);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    },
```

**Result Input**

[image]

**Result Fragment**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the fragment will try to load before the controller is initialised. You could add the fragment via your controller if that fits your requirements. Because of the load order, I see no other way. I added a small example below.

**Here are some tips:**

1. Be sure to pass the ID of the view in the XML fragment or you won't be able to access your controls with `this.byId("IDoftheControl")`. This is because it won't add the view's prefix if you add the fragment via the controller.
2. Add `this` as the last parameter in your fragment instantiation. If you don't, the functions you've added to your controls won't be executed because the controller will not be found for the fragment's controls.
3. If it fits your requirements better, add them via a `VBox` or other layout control. If you add other content to the view, it will be more readable like this.

Hope this helps you out, Dorien.

**View**

```
    <Page title="Fragment Test Page" id="idPage">   
    </Page>
```

**Controller**

```
    onInit: function(){
        this.onAddFragment();
    },

    onAddFragment: function(){
        var oFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "<PathToFragment>", this);
        this.byId("idPage").addContent(oFragment);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried debugging the order and you're right. I can do it your way, too. Thank you.